# Comparision time of ICP and NDT in Matching

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, icp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Theoretically NDT is faster than ICP. But when I measure the time of NDT by clock_t, it costs 10s, while ICP costs only 0.2s through the same way. I don't know what the reasons could be. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276644/comparision-time-of-icp-and-ndt-in-matching/) by [jjxforever](https://answers.ros.org/users/32750/jjxforever/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please check the implementation of ICP.
I guess it is implemented to use multi-thread or GPU acceleration.
By the way, NDT-D2D registration between two sets of about 3000 Gaussian components with multi-thread processing on Intel I7 CPU takes about 0.2-0.3 sec.

---

Originally posted by [hkhong](https://answers.ros.org/users/30001/hkhong/) with karma: 26 on 2018-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1